# Unable To Show Image In Picture Box Control From SQL Server Database In Windows Form Application

Tags: sql-server, winforms, upload, picturebox

I want to add scanned images (Vehicle Documents) to SQL Server Database from my C# Windows Form Application. In the SQL Server database, the datatype for the column where scanned documents will be saved is Image where I want to store the image as an array for each scanned document. Here is my code that saves the data into the SQL Server database.

Browse Button Code:

```
        private void btnBrowseFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
            fileDialog.Filter = "image files|*.jpg;*.png;*.gif;*.icon;*.bmp;*.*";
            DialogResult dResult = fileDialog.ShowDialog();

            if (dResult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                pBoxVehicleDocument.Image = Image.FromFile(fileDialog.FileName);
            }
        }
```

Add Button Code:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string documentName, vehicleId;
    documentName = txtDocumentName.Text;
    vehicleId = lblVehicleId.Text;
    
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    pBoxDocument.Image.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    mStream.ToArray();

    //The documentName, vehicleId and imageArray to be passed to AddVehicleDocuments Method within Vehicles Class.

    //No I am getting invalid arguments exception on AddVehicleDocuments() method.
    Vehicles.AddVehicleDocuments(documentName, vehicleId, imageArray);
}
```

And Finally the AddVehicleDocuments Method Code within Vehicles Class:

```
public static void AddVehicleDocuments(string documentName, int vehicleId, byte[] imageString)
        {
            string query = string.Format("insert into tblDocuments values ('{0}', {1}, {3})", documentName, vehicleId, imageString);
            DataAccess.Execute(query);
        }
```

Now, the following code is for image selection. I am not sure how can I convert the array values from the database back to a Picture Box on the Windows Form:

```
private void childDocumentDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int documentId = Convert.ToInt32(lblDocumentId.Text);
    DataRow dr = Vehicles.GetDocumentDetailsById(documentId);

    txtDocumentName.Text = dr["DocumentName"].ToString();
    txtVehicleNo.Text = dr["VehicleNo"].ToString();
    //here the image array from the database will locate in dr["VehicleDocument"];
    

    pBoxDocument.Image = //Need to write my code here
}
```

The DataRow dr contains all of the three records for the given document i.e. DocumentName, VehicleNo/VehicleID, and the byte string but the Picture Box Control still do not show the target image. Just need some expert suggestion in this regard.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: In `btnAdd`, after `pBoxDocument.Save()`, just pass `mStream.ToArray()` to `AddVehicleDocuments()`, remove `imageArray`. In `AddVehicleDocuments()`, the format string is wrong, in two different ways (`imageString`? That's a byte array. Is that coming from a previous *version* of the code. Check what parameters you're adding to the query) -- You have `pBoxVehicleDocument.Image = Image.FromFile(...)` and `pBoxDocument.Image.Save()`: is that correct? What Image are you trying to save?

Comment: @Jami, I have modified my question as per my recent changes to the code. I also have modified the datatype for the image to be Verbinary(MAX) in the database. May you please go through it again?

Comment: @Jami, also please not that pBoxVehicleDocument and pBoxDocument were two different controls on different forms. But now, I have updated their names.

Comment: `mStream.ToArray();` is a method that returns a value, pass that to the function. Your query is wrong (in more that one way), as already mentioned: you have to pass the bytes as the value of a command Parameter. -- Still not clear why you're showing `pBoxVehicleDocument` getting the Image and `pBoxDocument` saving it. Why don't you simply store the Image's bytes from the beginning, using `File.ReadAllBytes()` instead of `Image.FromFile()`, which also locks the Image file. But, most of all, revisit the method you're trying to use to save the Image: that's quite wrong, in all its parts.

Comment: I have a parent and child forms in this application. When a user browses the image from a file, I want to use it in the Picture Box so users can see the image he/she is about to upload. Then the Image is stored in the database using the AddVehicleDocuments() Method. After successful insertion, I want to allow users to check the document(image) for a specific vehicle. And that's why I have added a child from with another Picture Box so user can see the saved image for that vehicle. This second Picture Box will actually represent the image in the database. That's all, what I want.

Comment: As mentioned: 1. the original Image (from File) is stored (wrong) in `pBoxVehicleDocument` 2. After that, you're trying to save to a stream the Image that's in `pBoxDocument`. 3. You pass the byte array to a method that should store the Image in a database, but it's completely wrong, from the ground-up. Start from this last point, the others can wait. To insert data in a database, use Command Parameters, where you add the actual values to store. Remove that `string.Format()` thing to start over.

Comment: @Jimi, using the Command Parameters, I resolved the problem. Thanks for suggesting modification in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I was sure as per my research, that the Image data type on SQL Server-Side will work for me to store scanned documents for a vehicle. However, I modified my code later and used Verbinary(MAX) as the data type for storing images in the database.

I modified my insertion code which now looks like this:

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string documentName, vehicleId;
    documentName = txtDocumentName.Text;
    vehicleId = lblVehicleId.Text;
    
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
    pBoxDocument.Image.Save(mStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    byte[] imagesBytes = mStream.ToArray();

    Vehicles.AddVehicleDocuments(documentName, vehicleId, imagesBytes);
}
```

And the image selection code looks like:

```
private void childDocumentDetails_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int documentId = Convert.ToInt32(lblDocumentId.Text);
    DataRow dr = Vehicles.GetDocumentDetailsById(documentId);

    txtDocumentName.Text = dr["DocumentName"].ToString();
    txtVehicleNo.Text = dr["VehicleNo"].ToString();
    byte[] imageString = (byte[]dr["VehicleDocument"]);
    MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(imageString);

    pBoxDocument.Image = Image.FromStream(mStream);
}
```

Thanks to @Jimi for suggesting code modifications.